# Why does the Red Skull say Gamora's wrong father?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, avengers-infinity-war

When Gamora and Thanos arrive at Vormir, the Red Skull calls each one by his and their father’s/mother’s name. However, he says Gamora's father is Thanos, which we know isn't true. (Her family was killed by the Black Order).

> Stonekeeper: Welcome, Thanos, son of A'lars. Gamora, daughter of Thanos.

So why did the stone keeper (Red Skull) say that? Did he know who Gamora's real father was? He definitely seems to know in *Avengers: Endgame*:

> RED SKULL (2014): Natasha, daughter of Ivan. Clint, son of Edith.

Was the Red Skull lying? Why would he? Did he really think Thanos was Gamora's real father? What prevented him from knowing the truth?

Also: Why is he inconsistent by calling Gamora, Thanos and Natasha by their father, and Clint by his mother?

Comment: Is he inconsistent? Is there any evidence that A'lars is the name of Thanos's father, and not his mother?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist even if A'lars is the mother he is still inconsistent! he calls half the people by their father and half by their mother.

Comment: Using the person's mother if they're male (Clint, Thanos) and the person's father if they're female (Natasha, Gamora) is consistent.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist A’Lars is Thanos’ father I believe.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot- You are correct, Sir; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mentor_(A%27lars)

Comment: Are you implying that adoption isn't a thing?

Comment: Another possibility is that he listed the parent who had the most influence.  He is the guardian of the Soul stone after all.  Perhaps he was given more insight into the heart of their being? Just speculation.

Answer (score 16):

Thanos isn’t Gamora’s “wrong” father, he’s her adoptive father, albeit forcibly adopted. Adoptive families are still families and she’s been in the adoptive one for longer than her real one. She *is* a Daughter of Thanos, and was at least for a time a part of the Black Order and one of the Children of Thanos.

> **Thor:** You seem to know a great deal about Thanos.
>
> **Drax:** Gamora... is the daughter of Thanos.
>
> **Thor:** Your father killed my brother.
>
> **Peter Quill:** Oh, boy. Stepfather. Technically, she hates him as much as you do.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War*</sub>

Using either the adoptive father or the real father’s name would have been fine (though I don’t think we know her real father’s name in the MCU) but it also serves as a set up for the sacrifice. They both love each other, albeit not quite in the traditional sense. By using Thanos in this scene it sets the precedent than Thanos does truly love her for the sacrifice.

> **Red Skull:** In order to take the stone you must lose that which you love. A soul... for a soul.
>
> **Gamora:** All my life, I dreamed of a day... a moment when you would get what you deserved. And I was always so disappointed. But now... you kill and torture... and you call it mercy. The universe has judged you. You asked it for a prize, and it told you no. You failed. And do you wanna know why? Because you love nothing. No one.
> Really? Tears?
>
> **Red Skull:** They're not for him.
>
> **Gamora:**!No. This isn't love.
>
> **Thanos:** I ignored my destiny once. I cannot do that again. Even for you. I'm sorry, little one.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War*</sub>

Comment: Black Widow considers the Avengers as her family. shouldn't her father be Nick Fury or something?

Comment: @MBEllis there’s a difference between thinking of people as your family and your real family, biological or otherwise. There’s no indication she thinks of anyone as a father figure.

Comment: "It is my curse to know all who journey here." - So Red Skull knows about the relationships between the characters and their parents

Comment: @Valorum And he should also know who is each character's real parent

Comment: @MBEllis - You're assuming that he's basing it on biology.

Comment: @Valorum you're assuming he's basing on the relationship. Natasha didn't even know her father's name before red skull says it. She certainly doesn't have a daughter relationship with him, and yet red skull sticks to the facts and just says her father's name. Why is Gamora different?

Comment: @MBEllis - His welcome is intended to prove that he 'knows' each person. How better to prove it than to name a parent? Even better if they're adopted to name their "real" parental figure

Comment: @Valorum that is possible, but he could have logically just as well stay consistent and say the biological father. My question is why he didn't. It isn't wrong to say that in some way Thanos is Gamora's father, but it's also right that he isn't her father. Why did the guardian choose the adopted father and not the biological, as he did with Natasha?

Comment: @MBEllis Gamora was adopted.  Was Natasha?  Or was she just a permanent orphan?  Red Skull may just be referencing their *most recent* Parent, and Natasha may literally *not have had one* since her biological parents.

Answer (score 3):

Probably because despite everything they think of each other as father and daughter. Atleast Thanos did. And as evidenced by her tears when it seemed to Gamora that she had killed Thanos on Knowhere, she might've cared for him as well.

Comment: They don't just think of each other as father and daughter, _they are_ father and daughter, just not biologically. Although Thanos' opinion here likely shouldn't matter as Red Skull is talking about Gamora not Thanos.

Comment: I want to point out as well that I don't think there's any doubt that she cared for him, she was raised by him, taught by him and fought at his side on his mission. She never wouldn't care for him; she just stopped believing in his mission along the way.